# How to automatically move a fully downloaded file to a new directory

Tags: bash, wget, rsync

I am using wget to download files a group of files to be ingested in a program. I know I can use the "-P" to send the file to a tmp directory, but I am unsure what the best method is to move the file to the needed destination once fully downloaded. Is rsync the best way to move the files or is another method preferred using scripting?

Comment: Crossposting http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206751/74329 ?

Comment: `mv` works fine. I just wasn't sure if it was the best method. I am basically downloading a database of files every so many hours and I wasn't sure if `mv` was the best way. Right now I am saving the file to a temporary directory with wget and then running the command to `mv` in the script when wget closes.

Comment: Ok, on the other hand `rsync` after `wget` has finished would also work fine if you download mutiple files at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to move a file if the download is properly done then make a move or if it is not downloaded properly then no need of move, then you can use "LOGICAL AND" between the commands of `wget` and `mv`

```
wget http://mysite.example.com/file1.tgz && mv file1.tgz /new_dest/
```

Answer (score 2):

wget -0 /new_dest/file1.tgz http://mysite.example.com/file1.tgz

/new_dest/file1.tgz will be immediately touched and content downloaded will be piped to it.